# Arduous trigonometric simplification task

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I have equations that are products of sines and cosines that I want to integrate. As an example, the integrand may look something like this:

$-\cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  x (p+q)}{A}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  y (p-q)}{A}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  x (r+s)}{A}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  y
   (r-s)}{A}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  q x}{A}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  y (2 p+q)}{A}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  x (r+s)}{A}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi
    y (r-s)}{A}\right)-\cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  p x}{A}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  y (p+2 q)}{A}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  x (r+s)}{A}\right) \sin
   \left(\frac{\pi  y (r-s)}{A}\right)-\sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  s x}{A}\right) \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  x (p+q)}{A}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  y (p-q)}{A}\right)
   \sin \left(\frac{\pi  y (2 r+s)}{A}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  q x}{A}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  s x}{A}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  y (2
   p+q)}{A}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  y (2 r+s)}{A}\right)-\cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  p x}{A}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  s x}{A}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  y
   (p+2 q)}{A}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  y (2 r+s)}{A}\right)+\sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  r x}{A}\right) \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  x (p+q)}{A}\right) \sin
   \left(\frac{\pi  y (p-q)}{A}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  y (r+2 s)}{A}\right)-\cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  q x}{A}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  r x}{A}\right) \sin
   \left(\frac{\pi  y (2 p+q)}{A}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  y (r+2 s)}{A}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  p x}{A}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  r x}{A}\right)
   \sin \left(\frac{\pi  y (p+2 q)}{A}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  y (r+2 s)}{A}\right)$

$x$ and $y$ are the only variables - everything else is a constant.
Fortunately, as pointed out here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2425064/441529
It can be simplified by repeated application of the product-to-sum formula. Clearly this will be a very arduous task by hand, but a breeze for an appropriately programmed computer.

I have been trying to get Mathematica to help me, with some luck and also some issues. I have been applying the following rules:

```
CS = Cos[a_]*Sin[b_] :> (1/2)*(Sin[a + b] - Sin[a - b]);
SC = Sin[a_]*Cos[b_] :> (1/2)*(Sin[a + b] + Sin[a - b]);
CC = Cos[a_]*Cos[b_] :> (1/2)*(Cos[a + b] + Cos[a - b]);
SS = Sin[a_]*Sin[b_] :> (1/2)*(Cos[a - b] - Cos[a + b]);
```

Which work well to expand the trig functions to get someting like this:

$-\frac{1}{8} \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  x (p+q)}{A}-\frac{\pi  y (p-q)}{A}-\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  x (r+s)}{A}-\frac{\pi  y (r-s)}{A}\right)+\frac{1}{8} \sin
   \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  x (p+q)}{A}-\frac{\pi  y (p-q)}{A}+\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  x (r+s)}{A}-\frac{\pi  y (r-s)}{A}\right)+\frac{1}{8} \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  x
   (p+q)}{A}+\frac{\pi  y (p-q)}{A}-\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  x (r+s)}{A}-\frac{\pi  y (r-s)}{A}\right)-\frac{1}{8} \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  x (p+q)}{A}+\frac{\pi  y
   (p-q)}{A}+\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  x (r+s)}{A}-\frac{\pi  y (r-s)}{A}\right)+\frac{1}{8} \sin \left(-\frac{\pi  y (2 p+q)}{A}+\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  q x}{A}-\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  x
   (r+s)}{A}-\frac{\pi  y (r-s)}{A}\right)-\frac{1}{8} \sin \left(-\frac{\pi  y (2 p+q)}{A}+\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  q x}{A}+\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  x (r+s)}{A}-\frac{\pi  y
   (r-s)}{A}\right)-\frac{1}{8} \sin \left(\frac{\pi  y (2 p+q)}{A}+\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  q x}{A}-\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  x (r+s)}{A}-\frac{\pi  y (r-s)}{A}\right)+\frac{1}{8} \sin
   \left(\frac{\pi  y (2 p+q)}{A}+\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  q x}{A}+\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi  x (r+s)}{A}-\frac{\pi  y (r-s)}{A}\right)\text{...}$

(The full thing is >10 times as long as this snippet! All terms have the same general form: - $\frac{1}{8} \sin (C x+D y)$)

This should be easily integrated now, but Mathematica's Integrate[] function won't solve the above for me, despite having no trouble with this equivalent integral:

```
Integrate[Sin[k*a + j*b], {a, a1, a2}, {b, b1, b2}]
    = (-Sin[b1 j + a1 k] + Sin[b2 j + a1 k] + Sin[b1 j + a2 k] - Sin[b2 j + a2 k])/(j k)
```

So my questions is either:

How can I coax Integrate[] into providing a solution?

or

How can I write a rule to apply to the above to produce the result of the integral?

I have tried both the above with no luck so far. Thank you!

Edit: Here's the Mathematica code if you would like to run it:
There are three types of wavefunction:

```
A1[x_, y_, p_, q_] := Cos[q*Sqrt[3]*Pi*x/A]*Sin[(2*p + q)*Pi*y/A] -    Cos[p*Sqrt[3]*Pi*x/A]*Sin[(2*q + p)*Pi*y/A] - Cos[(p + q)*Sqrt[3]*Pi*x/A]*Sin[(p - q)*Pi*y/A];
A2[x_, y_, p1_, q1_] :=   Sin[q1*Sqrt[3]*Pi*x/A]*Sin[(2*p1 + q1)*Pi*y/A] -   Sin[p1*Sqrt[3]*Pi*x/A]*Sin[(2*q1 + p1)*Pi*y/A] + Sin[(p1 + q1)*Sqrt[3]*Pi*x/A]*Sin[(p1 - q1)*Pi*y/A];
EE[x_, y_, p_, q_] := A2[x, y, p, q] + A1[x, y, p, q]*Sqrt[-1];
```

and the integrands are products of 2 such wavefunctions - e.g.

```
A1[x, y, p, q]*A2[x, y, r, s]
```

I then proceed to Expand[] and apply the above rules to the functions. They rapidly get far too long to copy/paste here.

(I start with A1[x, y, p, q]*A2[x, y, r, s]. I first use Expand[] once, then (the solution) /.CS, then /.SS, then Expand[] again and /.CS one more time, to arrive at the snippet above.)

EDIT 2:

I think I may have cracked it.

```
COL = Sin[a_] :> Sin[Collect[Collect[a, x], y]]
IN = Sin[k_ x + j_ y] :> (-Sin[b1 j + a1 k] + Sin[b2 j + a1 k] + Sin[b1 j + a2 k] - Sin[b2 j + a2 k])/(j k)
```

However the resulting formula is enormous. So large it caused my computer to crash when I attempted to simplify it!

Comment: Could you edit your question to include code for the integrand that we can copy/paste and run?  Moreover, can you post the exact code you used to expand the trig functions and do the integration?  You don't need to include the full output, but a sample (like you included, but it would be better in code form) would be nice.  Also, what happens with `Integrate`?  Does it run without stopping, or does it give up and return unevaluated?

Comment: In addition to @jjc385's comment, you could use [`TrigReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrigReduce.html) instead of manually coding the rules

Comment: @Mathe172 I tried this - but it's actually easier and faster to do it semi-manually (I.e. choose what rule to apply and when) to guide mathematica towards the form I want

Comment: @jjc385 I've just added the input code. I start with A1[x, y, p, q]*A2[x, y, r, s].  I first use Expand[] once, then (the solution) /.CS, then /.SS, then Expand[] again and /.CS one more time, to arrive at the snippet above.

Comment: For the integral I have tried everything from 
    `Integrate[blah[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]` to
    `Assuming[{x > 0, y > 0, x \[Element] Reals, y \[Element] Reals, a > 0,
   a \[Element] Reals, A \[Element] Reals, A > 0, p > 0, q > 0, 
  p \[Element] Integers, q \[Element] Integers, p1 > 0, q1 > 0, 
  p1 \[Element] Integers, q1 \[Element] Integers}, 
 Integrate[
  A1[x, y, p, q]*A2[x, y, p1, q1], {x, y} \[Element] 
   SSSTriangle[a, a, a]]]`

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out the formatting in these comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problems here. Your integrand is a sum of terms.

Every term can be integrated for its own easily. Here done for the first term.

```
Integrate[-Cos[(Sqrt[3] \[Pi] (p + q) x)/A] Sin[(
            Sqrt[3] \[Pi] (r + s) x)/A] Sin[(\[Pi] (p - q) y)/
             A] Sin[(\[Pi] (r - s) y)/A], {x, x1, x2}, {y, y1, y2}]

(*     -(A^2 (-(Cos[(Sqrt[3] \[Pi] (p + q - r - s) x1)/A]/(p + q - r - s)) + 
  Cos[(Sqrt[3] \[Pi] (p + q + r + s) x1)/A]/(p + q + r + s) + 
  Cos[(Sqrt[3] \[Pi] (p + q - r - s) x2)/A]/(p + q - r - s) - 
  Cos[(Sqrt[3] \[Pi] (p + q + r + s) x2)/A]/(
  p + q + r + 
   s)) ((p - q - r + s) Sin[(\[Pi] (p - q + r - s) y1)/
    A] + (-p + q - r + s) Sin[(\[Pi] (p - q - r + s) y1)/
    A] + (-p + q + r - s) Sin[(\[Pi] (p - q + r - s) y2)/
    A] + (p - q + r - s) Sin[(\[Pi] (p - q - r + s) y2)/
    A]))/(4 Sqrt[3] \[Pi]^2 (p - q + r - s) (p - q - r + s))     *)
```

Now make a list of terms of the integrand (here done for the first three terms) and integrate each listelement alone and then sum up.

```
integrand = -Cos[(Sqrt[3] \[Pi] (p + q) x)/A] Sin[(
   Sqrt[3] \[Pi] (r + s) x)/A] Sin[(\[Pi] (p - q) y)/
   A] Sin[(\[Pi] (r - s) y)/A] + 
   Cos[(Sqrt[3] \[Pi] q x)/A] Sin[( \[Pi] (2 p + q) y)/A] Sin[(
   Sqrt[3] \[Pi] (r + s) x)/A] Sin[(\[Pi] (r - s) y)/A] - 
   Cos[(Sqrt[3] \[Pi] p x)/A] Sin[( \[Pi] (p + 2 q) y)/A] Sin[(
   Sqrt[3] \[Pi] (r + s) x)/A] Sin[(\[Pi] (r - s) y)/A];

Plus @@ (Integrate[#, {x, x1, x2}, {y, y1, y2}] & /@ 
           List @@ integrand)

(* result too long to show here  *)
```

Appendix:

Since you told, that calculation takes very long

and noticing, that the terms of the integrand are all of the same form

Cos[a x]*Sin[b x]*Sin[c y]*Sin[d y]

there is a much faster way, applying a rule instead of integrating each time again.

```
intrule = 
          Cos[a_ x]*Sin[b_ x]*Sin[c_ y]*Sin[d_ y] -> 
      Integrate[
          Cos[a x]*Sin[b x]*Sin[c y]*Sin[d y], {x, x1, x2}, {y, y1, y2}]

(*     Cos[x a_] Sin[x b_] Sin[y c_] Sin[
           y d_] -> ((-b Cos[a x1] Cos[b x1] + b Cos[a x2] Cos[b x2] - 
       a Sin[a x1] Sin[b x1] + 
       a Sin[a x2] Sin[b x2]) (-d Cos[d y1] Sin[c y1] + 
       c Cos[c y1] Sin[d y1] + d Cos[d y2] Sin[c y2] - 
       c Cos[c y2] Sin[d y2]))/((a^2 - b^2) (c^2 - d^2))     *)
```

Test it with the first term of the integrand

```
i1 = Integrate[term1, {x, x1, x2}, {y, y1, y2}];

t1 = term1 /. intrule;

t1 - i1 // TrigExpand // FullSimplify

(*     0     *)
```

The code, now by orders of magnitude faster, is now

```
Plus @@ ((# /. intrule) & /@ List @@ integrand)
```

Comment: It works! (But it is incredibly slow and caused my computer to crash twice! probably the laptop's fault more than anything else). Actually, the most useful (and faster) result was when I applied it to the fully expanded function, and changed the integral to over a triangle using `Plus @@ (Integrate[#, {x, y} \[Element] SSSTriangle[a, a, a]] & /@ 
   List @@ integrand)`

Comment: I just appended an improvement to my former answer.